# Coupon Code is not working when overwrite the discount calculation

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon

There will be a one time charge for each product called as handling charges. So, I did below,

Reference Tutorial is: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/

```
       <sales>
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <discount>
                        <class>Namo_Packing_Model_Courier</class>
                        <after>subtotal</after>
                    </discount>
                </totals>
            </quote>
        </sales>
```

Inside `local/Namo/Giftcarfs/Model/Courier.php`

```
<?php

class Namo_Packing_Model_Courier extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract {

    public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {
            if ($address->getData('address_type') == 'shipping')
                return $this;

                $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
                $courier_fee = 0;

                    $helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_configuration');

                    $totalCourierFee = 0;
                    foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
                        $courierFee = $item->getCourierFee();
                        $totalCourierFee = $totalCourierFee+$courierFee;
                    }
                $address->setCourierFee($totalCourierFee);
                $address->setBaseCourierFee($totalCourierFee);


                $address->setGrandTotal($grandTotal + $address->getCourierFee());
                $address->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal + $address->getBaseCourierFee());

            return $this;
    }

    public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {

            if ($address->getData('address_type') == 'shipping')
                return $this;

            $amt = $address->getCourierFee();

            if ($amt != 0) {


                $address->addTotal(array(
                    'code' => 'Discount',
                    'title' => 'Courier Fee',
                    'value' => $amt
                ));
            }

        return $address;
    }

}
```

After adding this if I apply coupon code, I am getting error message as

> Coupon code "3A46-ZF1G-WE0X" is not valid.

If I comment `<sales>...</sales>` coupon code working fine.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue,

XML handler `discount` is the default Magento XML handler for applying coupon code. I changed `<discount>` into `<courier_fee>` Now it is working fine,

I changed below into

```
        <sales>
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <discount>
                        <class>Namo_Packing_Model_Courier</class>
                        <after>subtotal</after>
                    </discount>
                </totals>
            </quote>
        </sales>
```

like below

```
        <sales>
            <quote>
                <totals>
                    <courier_fee>
                        <class>Namo_Packing_Model_Courier</class>
                        <after>subtotal</after>
                        <before>grand_total</before>
                    </courier_fee>
                </totals>
            </quote>
        </sales>
```